# Problems installing iPhone final 3.2 SDK on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, iphone, installation, xcode, sdk

I downloaded the latest iPhone SDK (`xcode_3.2.2.2_and_iPhone_SDK_3.2_final.dmg`) from Apple and uninstalled the old SDK before the install.

I double-clicked the `.dmg` file and got the following pop-ups:

> The following Disk Images couldn't be found

and

> xcode_3.2.2.2_and_iPhone_SDK_3.2_final.dmg is not recognized

I am using OS 10.6.3

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

My first suggestion would to be redownload it just in case the file is corrupt or something. (about 1-5 hours of waiting, I know.) but... If the problem persists then it is possibly a more serious issue.